Expected number of children

A couple decides to start having children and keep having children until they have more girls than boys (note that this means they stop having children if their first child is a girl). How many children do they expect to have?

I intuitively think that the‏‏‎ ‎expected‏‏‎ ‎value‏‏‎ ‎is ‎$2$‏‏‎ ‎children‏‏‎. ‎If‏‏‎ ‎the‏‏‎ ‎couple‏‏‎ ‎stops‏‏‎ ‎after‏‏‎ ‎the‏‏‎ ‎first‏‏‎ ‎girl,‏‏‎ ‎the‏‏‎ ‎expected‏‏‎ ‎number‏‏‎ ‎of‏‏‎ ‎children‏‏‎ ‎is‏‏‎ ‎clearly‏‏‎ ‎$1$.‏‏‎ ‎If‏‏‎ ‎they‏‏‎ ‎‎have‏‏‎ ‎at‏‏‎ ‎least‏‏‎ ‎one‏‏‎ ‎boy‏‏‎ ‎and‏‏‎ ‎then‏‏‎ ‎stop‏‏‎ ‎at‏‏‎ ‎the‏‏‎ ‎next‏‏‎ ‎girl,‏‏‎ ‎the‏‏‎ ‎expectation‏‏‎ ‎calculation‏‏‎ ‎reaffirms‏‏‎ ‎the‏‏‎ ‎value‏‏‎ ‎of‏‏‎ ‎$2$.
Is there a mathematical way to find a concrete answer to this?

$2$ is the answer the the question "How many children do they expect to have when the first girl is born?"  But the answer to the question "How many children do they expect to have when they have more girls than boys?" is very much larger and is indeed infinite (though with unlimited time and budget, the probability of this eventually happening in finite time would be $1$.)

So what would the expected number of children be if you had to choose between the following options: 1, 2, 4, 8, and 16?

The probability you need $1$ child is $\frac12$, $3$ children is $\frac1{2^3}$, $5$ is $\frac{2}{2^5}$, $7$ is $\frac{5}{2^7}$, $9$ is $\frac{14}{2^9}$ etc. where the numerators are the Catalan numbers so odd $k$ children with probability $\frac{k-1 \choose(k-1)/2}{\frac{k+1}2 2^k}$.  Once you have done the expectation sum up to $453$ children you exceed $16$; up to $1709$ children you exceed $32$, and so on.  In fact the expectation is infinite.

Oh, I see. Thank you so much for your thorough response!

The answer to this question is infinity
The sequence of children the couple may have can be represented as a sequence of "U; R" for boy and girl, respectively. All possible valid sequences of children the couple may have must satisfy two conditions:
The sequence contains an equal number of "U; R" and has an even length of "2k"
Beginning with U / R, the sequence will contain (at least) one more U / R until the very last symbol (where we finally get an equal number of "U; R")We may graph the valid sequences on a square grid, with "U; R" representing up/right movement by one square.
We notice all valid sequences represent paths completely above or completely below the main diagonal!
Such paths are closely related to Dyck-Paths. There are exactly "2 * C_{k-1}" of them with length "2k", where "C_k = C(2k; k) / (k+1)" is the k'th Catalan-Number.
Since there are a total of "22k = 4k " possible sequences of length "2k", the probability of the couple having "2k" children is
2k * P(2k)  =  2k * 2 * C(2k-2; k-1) / (k * 4^k)  =:  a_{k-1},
    ak  =  C(2k; k) / 4^kak  ~  1 / √(k)  >  1/k    for    k -> ∞

Since the sum over the harmonic sequence "1/k" diverges, so does the sum over "ak"

You are correct that it is infinite and related to Catalan numbers.  But when you first have  more girls than boys, you need an odd number of children.
